# Pycharm variable usage check and query expression

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

We know that Pycharm is capable of checking usage of variables. For a variable that is not used after definition, it would make it gray.

Recently, I learnt a new pandas technique - query. This one requires to write expression in a string. This makes variable usage checking difficult since variables are wrapped in a string.

I am wondering is there a method that I can adopt to avoid this situation - I have used that variable in a string but it still appears gray.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Suppose `df` is a dataframe containing two columns `year`, `value`. If I want to get data in `years = [2008,2009,2010]` with `pd.DataFrame.query()` , I would write:`df.query("year in @years", engine ='python' )`. In such case, Pycharm would think variable `years` is not used as wrapped in a string. I just want to know is there a way to fix this.

Comment: Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-52504 (thumbs up near the title)

Answer (score 1):

You can add just before your declaration: `#noinspection PyUnusedLocal`

For example:

```
#noinspection PyUnusedLocal
lst_studies_to_remove = df_ok["Study UID"].unique().tolist()
exports.query("`Study UID` not in @lst_studies_to_remove",inplace=True)
```

You can also add `_` to your variable name, so Pycharm inspection is not done.

```
_lst_studies_to_remove = df_ok["Study UID"].unique().tolist()
exports.query("`Study UID` not in @lst_studies_to_remove",inplace=True)
```